# Easy Contact Forms plugin does not work with PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

The WordPress plugin [Easy Contact Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-contact-forms/) doesn't with WordPress 3.9 and PHP 5.5.9

It doesn't show the form fields, nor you can edit, and it won't show the form in the website.

I notice because it gives me this error:

> Ajax error. Status =error  Internal Server Error

I look at the log files and see the error is in the file: 
*easy-contact-forms/easy-contact-forms-database.php* at line 152, due to the function `mysql_real_escape_string`

I tried to use another similar functions, but either doesn't work, or deletes data, or doesn't work for every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching the file code, you can realize that this plugin is not perfectly made, it's inconsistent. It changes it's MySQL connection !

One quick fix to make it work, (I know this is not the best way):

in the *wptn* function  add:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
```

Like this:

```
function wptn($query) {

        global $wpdb;

        mysql_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword');
        $query = str_replace("#wp__", $wpdb->prefix, $query);
        return $query;

    }
```