# Wordpress ajax plugin not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I need a little help

I had to recover an entire wordpress server due to malware. After cleaning the code and restoring, everything went fine except for a plugin called easy2map, that posts a map with defined points. Apparently, it needs ajax access to write the map. Prior to the backup, the plugin worked fine. Now it only shows the maps when logged in to wp-admin. I've tried giving public permissions to admin-ajax.php through .htaccess but without success. no_priv actions are in the plugin code. I have no idea what happened. What am i missing?

Thank you

**edit:** When i'm not logged in, a debugger is telling admin-ajax.php is throwing a 302 error. Moved temporarily

**edit2** admin-ajax.php - 302 Moved Temporarily
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?mapID=316&action=retrieve_map_settings

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Where should php errors be showing? I am only aware of the browser developer console. Been trying to figure that one out! Shouldn't there be a log?

Comment: It's possible you have WordPress debugging set to false. You can set it to true in wp-config.php.

Comment: I set it to true and set debug logs to true aswell. It only reports two lines repeatedly:
[26-Sep-2014 12:49:10] enqueuing scripts
[26-Sep-2014 12:49:10] jquery0

Comment: I had the same problem once, it was due to a plugin with bad coding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648361/easy-contact-forms-plugin-does-not-work-with-php-5-5-9

Comment: Why did it work before? Or why did it stopped working? Where should i put the login safely, btw? The plugin main .php?

Comment: anyone? I'm really getting desperate with this

Answer (score -1):

Please add the following to your .htaccess file. This will solve the problem.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried it on the root .htaccess and wp-admin .htaccess. Neither worked =/
Also tried:
    <Files admin-ajax.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Satisfy any
    </Files>

Comment: Sorry... This bit of code helped me once, that's why I suggested you this.